# HTML 5 Content Security Policy more than one page (Ionic/AngularJS/Cordova)

Tags: angularjs, html, cordova, security, ionic-framework

How can I set more than one page to the meta-tag http-equiv of the content security policy? I have this :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'
    http://foo.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

But I also want **https://foo2.com** and http://www.foo3.com to be in there. I try adding a new meta line but it is not working.

Hope you can help me!

Comment: is this running from a server, or or something like phonegap/cordova?

Comment: Yes, I am using Ionic Framework with Cordova and Angular JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After few days searching and looking I found this and it seems to be working:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src
    'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.foo.com *.foo2.com *.foo3.com">
```